# Laravel complex scope querying relation (for review)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I wrote this and I'm just wondering if it's the best way to do it.
Orders have many transactions... Transactions belongTo order. I am querying order with ids greater than the last ID sent to fulfilment. Then I want only orders that have approved payment status or are offline payment type.

This code works, just wondering if it's the best way to do this :

```
/**
 * Get all orders pending fulfilment
 *
 * @param $query
 * @param $last_fulfiled
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeToFulfil($query, $last_fulfiled)
{
    return $query->where('id', '>', $last_fulfiled)
        ->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereHas('transactions', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', '>=', 5);
        })->orWhere('payment_method', '=', 2);
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the SQL syntax :

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`deleted_at` is null and `id` > ? and ((select count(*) from `transactions` where `transactions`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` and `status` >= ?) >= 1 or `payment_method` = ?)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely the correct Laravel approach for building this query. This almost always generates a pretty decently optimized query, usually a LEFT JOIN or a subquery or a combination of both.

If you want to see how optimal the resulting query would be, add `->toSql()` to the end of that query statement and post the raw query syntax here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the SQL syntax to my answer... Makes you realise how helpful Laravel is :)

Comment: I think the query built is pretty perfect. As long as you make sure to index the columns that you're filtering by, that'll be great.

Comment: Yes I did... Thanks for your kind help.